# How to set break point in the VS Code even after downloading and installing lldbCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I cannot figure out to set a breakpoint in VS Code. Things I have done after googling the problem include:

1. Go to Code->Perferences->Setting, search for "Allow Breakpoints Everywhere", and check it.
2. Download and install lldbCode.
3. Using -g flag for compiling.

However, I am still not able to get the breakpoint to work. I can see the red dot. However, after hitting F5, the debugger just goes through the entire program and generates the output right away.

The followings are the launch.json, main.c, and a simple makefile that I use for the test.

Am I missing anything? Or it's some sort of bug that I am not aware of.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

launch.json

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printHello();

int main() {
  printf("aHello World\n");
  printf("bHello World\n");
  printf("cHello World\n");

  printHello();
}

void printHello() {
  printf("\n1 hello\n");
  printf("2 hello\n");
}
```

makefile

```
hellomake: main.c
    clang -g -o hello main.c
```

OS: macOS High Sierra verson 10.13.6